# Error 'Login Required' while calling Google Analytics API from Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-analytics, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics-api, google-sheets-api

I use google scripts to fill Google Spreadsheet by Google Analytics data. 
 
Problem: I get `error: Login Required` when I call `=getCountOfNewUsers(B1,B2)` from my Spreadsheet file. 
 NOTE: when I run `runTest()` from google script project everything working OK. 
FYI: I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script) tutorial.

```
function runTest() {
  try {
    var results = getCountOfNewUsers(new Date(), new Date());
    Logger.log(results.totalsForAllResults["ga:newVisits"]);

  } catch(error) {
    Logger.log(error.message);
  }
}

function getCountOfNewUsers(date_from, date_till) {
  date_from = Utilities.formatDate(date_from, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  date_till = Utilities.formatDate(date_till, 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');      
  var tableId = 'ga:*****';

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, date_from, date_till, 'ga:newVisits', {});

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;    
  } else {
    throw new Error('No views (profiles) found');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oleg - I'm hitting this issue now (the function prompts for authentication if I run it from a script menu, but fails when referencing it from a sheet cell). Have you found a workaround?

Comment: Turns out you can't do it from a cell function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services

Answer (score 1):

This is not solution to your question but it directs you to easy better solution to your problem if your interested!, you can easily setup this solution in an hour!

**Details:**

Better Than A  writing our own script with Diligent Study and make Google scripts to fill Google Spreadsheet by Google Analytics data I use this **[Google Analytics Report Automation (Magic Script)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic)**

- This Magic Script allow you to simplifies this process and makes it
  easy to get the data you want so that you can focus on analysis and
  reporting.
- Custom API Dashboards - No Code Required it will save your burden for
  Writing Your Own Script.

[image]

About the Error Try following things

- Go to script editor, click on Resources > click on Use Google APIs.
- Click on "Google APIs Console".
- select APIs & auth > click on Registered apps.
- Do Register your script project as web application.
- select Certificate > Generate New Key .

Comment: thanks, but I can not find "Registered apps" on APIs & auth tab http://imgur.com/x40YwzN

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. Custom Functions cannot ask users to give access to personal data. So they are not suitable for all types of services, specifically those which need authorization for personal data.

Check this url to know which services you can use - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data